# Getting a Malloc() corrupted top size on function call

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc, mpi

Similar to my previous question, I'm working on a program to run off a Raspberry Pi 4 cluster. My current issue is that when I make a function call to four_thread, no matter what I get a malloc() corrupted top size call. I feel somewhat blind as this is likely an incredibly obvious issue, but I cannot find it myself. Fortunately, it seems to me that it's going wrong right as the function gets called, as "Made it to four_thread" does not get printed. Does anyone have any ideas? Also sorry, i'll probably post excess code to be clear that the other sections are not the issue.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define NUMC 4

struct BaseStats
{
    char * ticker;
    int errors;
    float currentPrice;
    float fiftyDayAverage;
    float twoHundredDayAverage;
    float fiftyTwoWeekHigh;
    unsigned long long marketCap;
    unsigned long long floatShares;
    float shortPercentOfFloat;
    float trailingPE;
    unsigned long long sharesOutstanding;
    float revenuePerShare;
    float profitMargins;
    float currentRatio;
    float quickRatio;
    float returnOnEquity;
    float returnOnAssets;
    float debtToEquity;
    float priceToSales;
    float priceToBook;
    unsigned long long averageVolume;
    unsigned long long volume;
    int rank;

};

void *set_Stats(void *z);
struct Tickers {
    char ** x;
    int length;
};
struct Tickers getTickers()  //returns a list of nasdaq stocks
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    char line[300];
    struct Tickers tickers;
    int length = 0;
    char url[60] = "ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/nasdaqtraded.txt";
    if(curl)
    {
        FILE *temp = tmpfile();
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)temp);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(temp)
        {
            rewind(temp);
            char c = fgetc(temp);
            while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),temp)) 
            {
                length++;
            }
            rewind(temp);
            length = length - 2;
            tickers.length = length;
            tickers.x = malloc(length * 7);
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), temp);
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), temp);
            for(int count = 0; count < length; count++)
            {
                char *string = line + 2;
                int tickLen = 0 ;// strstr(string, "|") - string;
                if(strstr(string, "|") - string;
                {
                     tickLen = strstr(string, "\") - string;
                     tickers.x[count] = malloc(tickLen);
                     strncpy(tickers.x[count], string, tickLen);
                     tickers.x[count][tickLen] = '\0';
                }
                fgets(line, sizeof(line), temp);
            }
            fclose(temp);
        }
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return tickers;
}
char * getStr (char ticker[])
{
    //uses curl to get a char * of a stock website
}

void four_thread(struct BaseStats results[], char **keys, int len)  //input the storage array, the tickers,
{
    printf("Made it to four_thread");                                   //and the length of the two arrays.
    void *ret;
    int keyCounter = 0;
    int coreCounter = 0;
    int ierr = 0;
    printf("Starting Thread Initialization");
    pthread_t thread[NUMC];
    printf("Ending Thread Initialization");
    int iterations = len / NUMC;
    int remainder = len % NUMC;
    while(iterations > 0)
    {
        for(coreCounter = 0; coreCounter < NUMC; coreCounter++)
        {   
            printf("CREATING THREAD");
            pthread_create(&thread[coreCounter], NULL, set_Stats,&keys[keyCounter + coreCounter]); 
        }
        for(coreCounter = 0; coreCounter < NUMC; coreCounter++)
        {
            pthread_join(thread[coreCounter], &ret);
            results[keyCounter + coreCounter] = *((struct BaseStats *)ret);
            free(ret);
        }
        keyCounter+= NUMC;
        iterations--;
    }
    for(coreCounter = 0; coreCounter < remainder; coreCounter++)
        pthread_create(&thread[coreCounter], NULL, set_Stats,&keys[keyCounter + coreCounter]);
    for(coreCounter = 0; coreCounter < remainder; coreCounter++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread[coreCounter], &ret);
        results[keyCounter + coreCounter] = *((struct BaseStats *)ret);
        free(ret);
    }
}



void *set_Stats(void *arg) //input the ticker
{
    int c;
    struct BaseStats *z = malloc(sizeof(struct BaseStats));
    strcpy(z->ticker,(char *)arg);
    char *str = getStr(z->ticker);
    // basically it uses str to initialize z's values.
    set_Rank(z);
    pthread_exit(z);    
}


char ** allocate_DD(int rows, int cols)
{
    char *data = (char *)malloc(rows*cols);
    char **array= (char **)malloc(rows*sizeof(char*));
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);
    return array;
}


int main() //Designed for one master, three slaves
{
    int my_id;
    char **myTicks;
    int myLen;

    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Datatype types[23] = {MPI_CHAR,MPI_INT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,
    MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG,MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG,
    MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_FLOAT,
    MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG, MPI_INT};
    MPI_Datatype MPI_Base_Stats;
    int blocklengths[23] ={7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    MPI_Aint offsets[23];
    offsets[0] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,ticker); offsets[1] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,errors);
    offsets[2] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,currentPrice); offsets[3] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,fiftyDayAverage);
    offsets[4] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,twoHundredDayAverage); offsets[5] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,fiftyTwoWeekHigh);
    offsets[6] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,marketCap); offsets[7] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,floatShares);
    offsets[8] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,shortPercentOfFloat); offsets[9] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,trailingPE);
    offsets[10]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,sharesOutstanding); offsets[11] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,revenuePerShare);
    offsets[12]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,profitMargins); offsets[13] = offsetof(struct BaseStats,currentRatio);
    offsets[14]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,quickRatio); offsets[15]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,returnOnEquity); 
    offsets[16]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,returnOnAssets); offsets[17]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,debtToEquity); 
    offsets[18]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,priceToSales); offsets[19]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,priceToBook); 
    offsets[20]= offsetof(struct BaseStats, averageVolume); offsets[21]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,volume); 
    offsets[22]= offsetof(struct BaseStats,rank);

    MPI_Type_create_struct(23,blocklengths,offsets,types, &MPI_Base_Stats);
    MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_Base_Stats);
    if(my_id == 0) // meaning this process is a host job
    {
        struct Tickers tickers = getTickers();
        int length = tickers.length / 4;
        int remainder = tickers.length % 4;
        myLen = length+remainder;
        myTicks              = allocate_DD(length + remainder, 7);
        char ** NodeOneTicks = allocate_DD(length, 7);
        char ** NodeTwoTicks = allocate_DD(length, 7);
        char ** NodeThrTicks = allocate_DD(length, 7);
        int count = 0;
        int x = 0;
        while(x < myLen)
        {
            strcpy(myTicks[x], tickers.x[count]);
            count++;
            x++;

        }
        x = 0;
        while(x < length)
        {
            strcpy(NodeOneTicks[x], tickers.x[count]);
            count++;
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        while(x < length)
        {
            strcpy(NodeTwoTicks[x], tickers.x[count]);
            count++;
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        while(x < length)
        {
            strcpy(NodeThrTicks[x], tickers.x[count]);
            count++;
            x++;
        }
/*      MPI_Send(&length,1, MPI_INT,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(NodeOneTicks[0],length * 7,MPI_CHAR,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        free(NodeOneTicks[0]);
        free(NodeOneTicks);
        MPI_Send(&length,1, MPI_INT,2,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(NodeTwoTicks[0],length * 7,MPI_CHAR,2,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        free(NodeTwoTicks[0]);
        free(NodeTwoTicks);
        MPI_Send(&length,1, MPI_INT,3,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(NodeThrTicks[0],length * 7,MPI_CHAR,3,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        free(NodeThrTicks[0]);
        free(NodeThrTicks);
*/

    struct BaseStats *myStats = calloc(myLen, sizeof(struct BaseStats));
    printf("Ticker 31 = %s\n", myTicks[31]);
    four_thread(myStats, myTicks, myLen);
    printf("%s at a rank of %d\n", myStats[1].ticker, myStats[1].rank);

    else // must be slave process
    {
        myLen = 4;
//      MPI_Recv(&myLen,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        myTicks = allocate_DD(myLen, 7);
//      MPI_Recv(myTicks[0], myLen * 7,MPI_CHAR,0,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        myTicks[0] = "TSLA";
        myTicks[1] = "AAPL";
        myTicks[2] = "MSFT";
        myTicks[3] = "SPY";
//      printf("%s\n", myTicks[0]);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: `int tickLen = strstr(string, "|") - string;` might fail. Then you get a very large len and so malloc will fail.

Comment: `tickers.x = malloc(length * 7);` Are your pointers 7 bytes long?

Comment: `sub[6] = '\0';` What about `tickLen`? This is UB if `tickLen` is less than 7. The whole variable `sub` seems to be a bit useless. You can directly copy `tickLen` bytes into `tickers.x[count]`

Comment: @Gerhardh I believe each ticker had a length of 7 at max, but I can try fixing it from there. I will try keeping in Sub at first but I will keep that in mind if this first test works.

Comment: @Gerhardh Correction. The address not mapped was a one time error. I am recieving still a corrupted top size in addition to many more characters than I should be when I print myticks, for example for myTicks[31]; ABR$AABR$B and so on instead of abr$a.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sorry, I totally misunderstood your comment. Placing that into an if statement fixed the unnecessary characters (and a few other changes), but I'm back at the corrupted top size / corrupted double linked list.

Comment: `printf` writes to `stdout` which is _buffered_ by default. Unless you flush it manually (or, by convention, write a newline `'\n'`), not seeing a message doesn't prove the code was not reached. Are you debugging this on some platform other than Raspberry Pi? Can you just use valgrind, or an address sanitizer? Or a debugger?

Comment: @Useless Unfortunately I am debugging this on the raspberry pi, as getting libcurl was a bit of a hassle for windows machines. I've tried using the gdb debugger, but it would always tell me there was a problem with Raise.c, saying the file did not exist.

Comment: You still malloc only 7 bytes to hold a pointer. That might be OK for the raspi, but not for a modern PC or a raspi with 64 bit OS.

Comment: Did you add `\n` to your prints to see what is really printed? Did you try to remove the MPI stuff to narrow down the problem? Or remove the CURL stuff and read from a local file` Your code is also neither complete, nor minimal.

Comment: `tickers.x[count] = malloc(tickLen);` You need to add +1 for the `\0` byte.

Comment: @Gerhardh I actually originally wrote this section, then once it seemed to work, i started the mpi stuff. Once I got the mpi sends working, this stopped. I deleted some of the code between here and stackoverflow, as it is a stocks program and I thought giving too much information would be a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct BaseStats
{
    char * ticker;
```

...

```
void *set_Stats(void *arg) //input the ticker
{
    int c;
    struct BaseStats *z = malloc(sizeof(struct BaseStats));
    strcpy(z->ticker,(char *)arg);
```

The [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function expects the first argument to be an already-allocated array big enough to contain a copy of the second array. As a rule of thumb - this function is never safe and you should never use it.

Since you haven't initialized `z->ticker` at all, it *definitely* isn't a valid destination for `strcpy`. You're writing to an indeterminate location, which is absolutely Undefined Behaviour. Probably you should just write `z->ticker = strdup((char *)arg)` instead.

`BaseStates` has so many fields it'd be hard to initialize them all manually anyway, so you should either use [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) or manually zero your malloc'd memory.

Comment: I have edited the code on the raspberry pi to do this now. However, the program will only run correctly in gdb, while in mpirun it will refuse to get very far, claiming a segmentation fault for an address not mapped.

Comment: Correction. I either made a stupid error or it was a one time problem, the program is currently having no issues. Thank you so much!